# Vue / Nuxt - Content Api - Filter Json on category

Tags: json, vue.js, nuxt.js

Am trying to build a portfolio in Nuxt. The content of the portfolio is in GoogleSheets. Via GoogleSheets Api I created an portfolio.json in the Nuxt/Content folder. The presentation of the individual items and the overview of all the items is working.

Every portfolio item is in a category, I have a few categories. I want to be able to filter the items based on those categories.

Been trying to create a filter on the Portfolio page, but haven't succeeded yet. I have tried three different approaches, they are based on examples I found online.

example frontend, with dummy content: https://dl5en.sse.codesandbox.io
code : https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxt-content-filter-json-dl5en

1. attempt : recreated the example I saw on Youtube. Problem to get the filters working at all.
2. attempt : used a dev.to example to create filters. Problem, no items showing on first page visit. Would like to show them all at first visit.
3. attempt : used example in a reddit article to create filters. Problem, only items of one category are showing on first page visit. Would like to show them all at first visit.

If someone could give me some pointers on how to solve this problem(for one of the attempts), this is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found solution. updated the Codesandbox with example. including reset filter button and active css class.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxt-content-filter-json-dl5en?file=/pages/reddit2/index.vue